# I can't resize a partition with GParted

Tags: ubuntu, partition, gparted

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux.

I recently had an issue with my computer that made it impossible to boot windows. Turns out windows had corrupted system files.

I want to switch to Ubuntu without losing any of my data. I followed a tutorial on Youtube on how to create new partitions using a flash drive, but when I tried resizing my `/dev/sdb1` partition in GParted it just wouldn't let me do so.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu in my HDD that I mainly use for storing documents,games,music, and photos. I don't know much about computers someone please help me there's so much work I can lose if I don't fix this issue

Comment: Slow down - panic will only make things worse. Have you created a backup? Messing with partitions without exactly knowing what you're doing will most likely lead to data loss. If you're not careful, you will overwrite your windows files with your Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that sdb1 is your Windows partition?

When I installed Ubuntu on my computer, I just had to press the "install next to Windows" button and everything worked. But this is not possible if you have used BitLocker encryption in Windows.
It is Bitlocker that can interfere with you if you have used it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).